# Configurando CORS no Spring Security

Tags: java, ajax, spring-boot, spring-security, cross-domain

Preciso configurar o Spring Security para aceitar requisição de aplicações externas. Não sei com fazer, tenho um projeto em Spring Boot e Spring Security onde só aceita requisição da mesma origem. Deve aceitar requisição em AJAX usando angular.

Códigos:

Spring Security:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
//@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImp userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenAuthenticationService getTokenAuthenticationService() {
        return new TokenAuthenticationService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/","/index.html","/recuperarSenha","/admin/**", "/app/**","/favicon.ico","/install/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.headers().cacheControl();

        http.cors().disable() // disable csrf for our requests.
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/conectado").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/login").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/install/admin").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/login/recuperarSenha").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/api/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        // We filter the api/login requests
        .addFilterBefore(new JWTLoginFilter("/login", authenticationManager(), getTokenAuthenticationService()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        // And filter other requests to check the presence of JWT in header
        .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(getTokenAuthenticationService()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());

    }

}
```

E Angular-js:

```js
$scope.logar = function(login){

            $http.post("http://192.168.0.13:8088/onblox/login",login)
            .success(function(response){
                $scope.response1 = response;
            })
            .error(function(error){
            });

            }
```

Comment: Tentou usar a anotação `@CrossOrigin(origins = "ip")` no seu Rest Controller?

Comment: tentei  "@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://192.168.0.9:8085", maxAge = 3600)
@RequestMapping(value="/login")
public class LoginController extends ControllerImpl<Login, Long>{ mais ainda ta me dando erro :  No content to map due to end-of-input

Comment: Veja se te ajuda: https://github.com/gleydson/SystemEPCTG-RestServer/blob/master/src/main/java/br/org/estacaoluz/epctg/util/CorsFilterUtil.java Nesse projeto eu estou usando SpringBoot no back e angular4 no front, com autenticação via token jwt e pra configurar o cors bastou adicionar esta classe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and()
        //... seu codigo
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST", "OPTIONS"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
   }
}
```

Outro detalhe, no seu código tem um trecho:

```
http.cors().disable() // disable csrf for our requests.
```

Não seria:

```
http.csrf().disable()
```

?